# How to choose salary of principal investigator on NIH grant?

Tags: funding, salary, research-proposal

I am writing a grant for the NIH, and I need to put a salary down for the PI. I was wondering, do I choose how much to put down, or is there a specific pre-determined amount?

Comment: Your university's grants office will know.

Comment: Are you that PI? In general, for a proposal, you need to develop a budget (and a budget justification) that lists how many months someone will work on the project; the person's monthly salary equals what their employer pays them as part of their regular contract -- i.e., you cannot just "choose" a salary. (In the case of NIH, there is an additional complication in that NIH has a cap, but that is a separate issue.)

Comment: Thank you. No, I am not that PI. I am the poor fellow who does all the scut work. I am pretty sure my PI gets paid something like $200,000. 5% of that amount is a huge amount when the grant we are applying for is only $150,000....? I can't pay them less?